# how to open .epub files in android

Tags: android

I'm doing an android application which needs to read .EPUB files.I'm using http://www.siegmann.nl/epublib/android epublib for achieving this. But I got below error:

```
01-09 12:52:09.691: E/AndroidRuntime(5490): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
01-09 12:52:09.691: E/AndroidRuntime(5490):     at com.example.epub.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:46)
01-09 12:52:09.691: E/AndroidRuntime(5490):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
01-09 12:52:09.691: E/AndroidRuntime(5490):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
```

I used one sample epub file in asset folder.still im getting this error. How could i resolve this?

My Code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    AssetManager assetManager = getAssets();
    try {
        // find InputStream for book
        InputStream epubInputStream = assetManager.open("sample.epub");

        // Load Book from inputStream
        Book book = (new EpubReader()).readEpub(epubInputStream);

        // Log the book's authors
        Log.i("epublib", "author(s): " + book.getMetadata().getAuthors());

        // Log the book's title
        Log.i("epublib", "title: " + book.getTitle());

        // Log the book's coverimage property
        Bitmap coverImage = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(book.getCoverImage()
                .getInputStream());
        Log.i("epublib", "Coverimage is " + coverImage.getWidth() + " by "
                + coverImage.getHeight() + " pixels");

        // Log the tale of contents
        logTableOfContents(book.getTableOfContents().getTocReferences(), 0);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e("epublib", e.getMessage());
    }
}

/**
 * Recursively Log the Table of Contents
 * 
 * @param tocReferences
 * @param depth
 */
private void logTableOfContents(List<TOCReference> tocReferences, int depth) {
    if (tocReferences == null) {
        return;
    }
    for (TOCReference tocReference : tocReferences) {
        StringBuilder tocString = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < depth; i++) {
            tocString.append("\t");
        }
        tocString.append(tocReference.getTitle());
        Log.i("epublib", tocString.toString());

        logTableOfContents(tocReference.getChildren(), depth + 1);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: It's probably not the issue with library you're using. Show us the code (specifically, `MainActivity.onCreate()`. Please attach line numbers as well.

Comment: @kamituel Thanks for your reply.Above is my code i tried

Comment: Which line is line 46? That's where your exception is being thrown.

Comment: "Bitmap coverImage = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(book.getCoverImage()
     .getInputStream());"  This is line no.46

Comment: I just want to display the contents of the sample.epub file.Help me in this

Comment: please have a look at https://github.com/c99koder/lastfm-android/tree/master/app/docbook-xsl/epub

Comment: you can find some link from here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10206903/read-epub-file-in-android/14646211#14646211

Answer (score 2):

Based on your comments, error is in this line:

```
Bitmap coverImage = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(book.getCoverImage().getInputStream());
```

What is being thrown is `NullPointerException`, which means that:

1. `book` is null
2. `book.getCoverImage()` returns null
3. `book.getCoverImage().getInputStream()` returns null

You have to check which one of those is happening (use `Log.d()` and simply print out those values, or use debugger).

Possible reasons I can think of:

1. `book` could be null on example because "sample.epub" is missing, or it's format is invalid and `EpubReader` fails in decoding it.
2. Book does not have cover image?

Comment: Yes.Ive debugged.It returns no value from the file.But its .epub file only.I donno why its not opening./

Comment: Why do you mean by "it returns no value from the file"? Is `book` null? Or `epubInputStream` is null?

Comment: I used to download epub file from chrome://epubreader/content/reader.xul?id=3 and saved it in asset folder & tried.Still having same error

Comment: Okay, but which variable is null?

Comment: on book variable.in this line Book book = (new EpubReader()).readEpub(epubInputStream);

Comment: So, just to be clear, this line is executing, but `book` is null after wards?

Comment: yes correct.My code tree is looking like http://postimg.org/image/4yu03b6xz/ My test.epub file was downloaded from chrome://epubreader/content/reader.xul?id=3 am i in right path?

Comment: Have a look [here](https://github.com/psiegman/epublib/blob/ff14999c509e6e3b0289dd4c0cd6561cf8e50dee/epublib-core/src/main/java/nl/siegmann/epublib/epub/EpubReader.java#L106). This is the method you're using to parse epub. There is no way it returns null. Are you 100% sure `book` is null?

Answer (score 2):

Raeder part load epub file like this from assets folder

```
        AssetManager assetManager = getAssets();
        try {
            InputStream epubInputStream = assetManager.open("books/hafez.epub");
            Book book = (new EpubReader()).readEpub(epubInputStream);
            logContentsTable(book.getTableOfContents().getTocReferences(), 0);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("epublib", e.getMessage());
        }
```

load tableOfContent of epub

```
   private void logContentsTable(List<TOCReference> tocReferences, int depth) {
    if (tocReferences == null) {
        return;
    }
    for (TOCReference tocReference:tocReferences) {
        StringBuilder tocString = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < depth; i++) {
            tocString.append("\t");
        }
        tocString.append(tocReference.getTitle());
        RowData row = new RowData();
        row.setTitle(tocString.toString());
        row.setResource(tocReference.getResource());
        contentDetails.add(row);
        logContentsTable(tocReference.getChildren(), depth + 1);
    }
}

private class RowData{
    private String title;
    private Resource resource;

    public RowData() {
        super();
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public Resource getResource() {
        return resource;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public void setResource(Resource resource) {
        this.resource = resource;
    }

}
```

show a chapter of epub in WebView for example

```
    WebView  webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    WebSettings settings = webView.getSettings();
    settings.setDefaultTextEncodingName("utf-8");

    String displayString = rowData.getResource().getData();
    if (displayString != null)
        webView.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, displayString, "text/html", "UTF-8", null);
```